# Is there a way to turn off boss cutscenes?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

I've now finished Legend Mode, and am working my way through Adventure mode.  Quite often, it introduces bosses I've killed before.  And every single time, it starts with its intro cutscene.  It tends to get annoying the dozenth time you've been introduced to every single boss.  You can skip the cutscene, but I can't seem to figure out a way to turn them off completely.

How can I turn these things off completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Versions prior to 1.3.0**: You can't turn them off unfortunately, you can only skip them.

**Version 1.3.0 onwards**: An additional option has been added to disable boss introduction cutscenes in Adventure Mode

Comment: Cool, I was wondering why those characters weren't playable -- they seem to fit in rather well.